# Weird color dots on image after converting RGB to HSV and HSV to RGB

Tags: eclipse, image-processing, rgb, hsv

Good morning everyone. I am trying to write classes that can convert between RGB and HSV. Below is my code for transferring RGB to HSV and HSV to RGB. I tried to convert from RGB to HSV then HSV to RGB and then print the image. It looks like it works, but there are color dots on my image. I was wondering if someone can help explain this phenomenon.

```
public class RGBtoHSV {
private float normR, normG, normB, Cmax, Cmin, delta;
private float hue, saturation, value;
private int R, G, B;
int numP;
public RGBtoHSV(int R, int G, int B){
    this.R=R; this.G=G; this.B=B;
    normR = R/255; normG = G/255; normB = B/255;
    Cmax = Math.max(R, Math.max(G, B));
    Cmin = Math.min(R, Math.min(G, B));
    delta = Cmax - Cmin;
    calcHue();
    calcSaturation();
    calcValue();
}
public void calcHue(){
    if(delta == 0 ){
        hue = 0;
    }else if((Cmax == R)){
        hue = 60 * ((G-B)/delta);
    }else if(G  == Cmax){
        hue = 60 * (((B-R)/delta)+2);
    }else{
        hue = 60f * (((R-G)/delta)+4f);
    }
}
public void calcSaturation(){
    if(Cmax == 0)
        saturation = 0;
    else
        saturation = delta/Cmax;
}   
public void calcValue(){
    value = Cmax/255;
}

//getters
public float[] getHSV(){
    float[] HSV = new float[3]; 
    HSV[0] = hue;
    HSV[1] = saturation;
    HSV[2] = value;
    return HSV;
}
}
```

the code that converts HSV to RGB

```
public class HSVtoRGB {
int R, G, B;
float C, X, m;
float normR, normG, normB;
public HSVtoRGB(float H, float S, float V){
    C = S *V;
    X = C * (1 - Math.abs((H/60)%2 -1));
    m = V - C;

    if(H < 60){
        normR=C; normG=X; normB=0;
    }else if(H<120){
        normR=X; normG=C; normB=0;
    }else if(H <180){
        normR=0; normG=C; normB=X;
    }else if(H<240){
        normR=0; normG=X; normB=C;
    }else if(H<300){
        normR=X;normG=0;normG=C;
    }else{
        normR=C;normG=0;normG=X;
    }
    R = Math.round((normR+m)*255);
    G = Math.round((normG+m)*255);
    B = Math.round((normB+m)*255);
}
public int[] getRGB(){
    int [] RGB = new int[3];
    RGB[0] = R;
    RGB[1] = G;
    RGB[2] = B;
    return RGB;
}
```

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gya2K.png)

[Image after Conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRCSf.png)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at your code, but I'm confident I know what is causing the problem:  Somewhere in your code, values are being wrapped (e.g., from beyond "fully white") to the other end of the scale (e.g., somewhere near "fully black"), typically because a too-small variable is being used to hold temporary values.

For example, if you have a **signed byte** variable and use it to store the result of multiplying **16*9** (144, greater than the maximum +127 value of a signed byte), your signed byte value is going to be **-16** - which will produce "unexpected" results.

**EDIT**

After looking at your code, I suspect part of your problem is mixed integer and float arithmetic:  Some places you use `60`, for example, and other places you use `60f`, which I assume means you want a floating point number in the calculation.  (I'm only guessing that, since you didn't specify what *language* you are working with.)  You need to use floating point numbers in *all* of the calculations.

Comment: I am using Java eclipse

Comment: So... you are programming in Java, using eclipse as the IDE for editing your code...  (I *thought* it looked like Java code..)